# Compiling C++ project with opencv using Cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm trying to build a simple C++ project that uses opencv to open an image, and when I build and run it from Visual Studio it works fine, but when i try using Cmake it gives a linking error.
My ultimate goal is to be able to send the project to another PC and be able to compile without having to install opencv (and even better without Cmake) but with just the includes, lib and dll.

---

CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(TestProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories("C:/opencv/build/include")

link_directories("C:/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib")

add_executable(TestExecutable main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TestExecutable opencv_world480)
```

---

Source code:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>


void draw(std::string shape) {
    std::string imagePath = "assets/" + shape + ".png";
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imagePath, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    for (int row = 0; row < image.rows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < image.cols; ++col) {
            cv::Vec4b pixel = image.at<cv::Vec4b>(row, col);
            if (pixel[3] == 0) {
                std::cout << ' ';                
            }
            else {
                int alpha = pixel[3];
                int red = (pixel[2] * alpha) / 255;
                int green = (pixel[1] * alpha) / 255;
                int blue = (pixel[0] * alpha) / 255;

                std::cout << "\033[48;2;" << red << ";" << green << ";" << blue << "m  "; //Print using the RGBA values
                std::cout << "\033[0m"; //Reset the color
            }                
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
}

int main() {
    //draw("test");
    std::cout << "Test1" << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

---

The error when building:

```
\[build\] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\\TestExecutable.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `draw(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)': [build] C:/Users/miche/Desktop/Test/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::\__cxx11::basic_string\<char, std::char_traits\<char\>, std::allocator\<char\> \> const&, int)'
\[build\] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/miche/Desktop/Test/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()' [build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/miche/Desktop/Test/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::\~Mat()'
\[build\] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've also tried different CMakeLists found online but they still give the linking error, I tried compiling using a Makefile and via terminal with a single command
`g++ -std=c++14 -I"C:\opencv\build\install\include\" main.cpp -o insert_name_here.exe -L"C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc16\lib" -lopencv_world480`.
Still gives the error.

Comment: `link_directories("C:/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib")` is wrong for MinGW. This is folder containing `msvc`  binaries. Instead use `pacman` in msys2 to install the correct opencv binaries: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-opencv?repo=ucrt64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-opencv?repo=ucrt64)